# Python & OpenCV - Find contours and coordinates of handwritten text in a form

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, ocr

I have a sample of scanned documents. This documents are forms (european accident statement) and I want to detect the handwritten text and draw contours over the handwritten text.

This first image is my original document:
[image]

I want to detect all handwritten text and draw bounding boxes over it like this:
[image]

I already tried to use [boxdetect](https://github.com/karolzak/boxdetect) but without success
After detect all fields in the document,the desired result should be the coordinates of all fields that the user need to fill in like:

```
|      Name           |        Vorname     |      Telefon
|---------------------|--------------------|----------------------
|[(101, 172, 63, 12)] |[(105, 177, 69, 18)]| [(109, 182, 74, 23)]
```

Comment: You need some code. The computer won't do it magically if you don't have code to do that. Please post the code that you have implemented and some answerable question about that code. The question as is now is not really asking anything.

Comment: I think this should be solved by first registering/aligning the picture to a template of the form, then *knowing* the locations of the entry boxes from the template and applying this info to the scan (extracting those regions).

Answer (score 1):

If the forms are all nearly identical, you could take a scan of an empty form, and subtract the empty form from the written form. Then you could apply a threshold and some other processing to create a binary mask of just the handwriting, and apply text detection to that.

Here is something I managed to create in a couple of minutes:
[image]

The code is something along the lines of this:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2


def size_filter(image, minimum):
    ## Find connected components
    labels, vals = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(image)[1:3]
    vals = vals[1:, cv2.CC_STAT_AREA]

    new_img = np.zeros_like(labels, np.uint8)

    if vals.size == 0 or max(vals) < minimum:
        return new_img

    new_img[np.isin(labels, np.arange(len(vals))[vals >= minimum] + 1)] = 255

    return new_img

## Find the difference between the written form and the empty form
difference = np.abs(written_form.astype(np.int16)-base_form.astype(np.int16))

## Apply a threshold to the form
text_mask = np.all(difference > 100, axis=2)

## Remove Noise
text_mask = size_filter(text_mask)
```

I only spent a few minutes working on this, so it's not perfect, but this could work with a bit of effort.

Comment: It seems to be a good approach but how can I assign the handwritten text to the name of the field after that? (see the desired result of the question). Thanks

Comment: If the forms are standard, then you can just find the bounding box of each field in an empty form, and then assign text within that bounding box to the field.